# Generating PDF file with Images in flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf

I need some help please... I am trying to generate a PDF file (text & Images) using flutter, so I used the PDF package `pdf: ^3.3.0`, the text is shown once I generated the PDF file but every time I try to insert an image the below error is showing...even the image is loading in the main screen...
the error is [image]

my code is as the following:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:duct_sizer/pdf_preview_screen.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final pdf = pw.Document();
  final image = pw.MemoryImage(File('images/duct.jpg').readAsBytesSync());

  writeOnPdf() async {
    // final profileImage = pw.MemoryImage(
    //   (await rootBundle.load('images/duct.jpg')).buffer.asUint8List(),
    // );

    pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a5,
      margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(32),
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return <pw.Widget>[
          pw.Header(level: 0, child: pw.Text("Easy Approach Document")),
          pw.Paragraph(
              text:
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Quisque sagittis purus sit amet. A arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin sed."),
          pw.Paragraph(
              text:
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Quisque sagittis purus sit amet. A arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin sed."),
          pw.Header(level: 1, child: pw.Text("Second Heading")),
          pw.Image(image),
          pw.Paragraph(
              text:
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Quisque sagittis purus sit amet. A arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin sed."),
          pw.Paragraph(
              text:
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Quisque sagittis purus sit amet. A arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin sed."),
          pw.Paragraph(
              text:
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Quisque sagittis purus sit amet. A arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin sed."),
        ];
      },
    ));
  }

  Future savePdf() async {
    final bytes = await pdf.save();

    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;

    File file = File("$documentPath/example.pdf");

    file.writeAsBytesSync(bytes);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("PDF Flutter"),
      ),

      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "PDF TUTORIAL",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34),
            ),
            Image(
              image: AssetImage('images/header.png'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          writeOnPdf();
          await savePdf();

          Directory documentDirectory =
              await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

          String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;

          String fullPath = "$documentPath/example.pdf";
          print(fullPath);

          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => PDFPreviewScreen(
                        path: fullPath,
                      )));
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.save),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

and the PDF preview page is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_full_pdf_viewer/flutter_full_pdf_viewer.dart';
import 'package:flutter_full_pdf_viewer/full_pdf_viewer_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter_full_pdf_viewer/full_pdf_viewer_scaffold.dart';

class PDFPreviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String path;

  PDFPreviewScreen({this.path});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PDFViewerScaffold(
      path: path,
    );
  }
}
```

please assets me

This is a new update on the pubspec.yaml file which shows the dependencies & the images identifications
[image]
also As I said earlier the photo is displayed in the main App direct, but the the PDF this error will happen

Comment: Did you declare image in `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Yes, also I added the Image to the App screen to make sure that the image is there.

Comment: you need to write the path as `assets/images/header.png`.

Comment: Still Same Issue if I kept the code ``` class MySecondHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final pdf = pw.Document();
  final image =
      pw.MemoryImage((File('assets/images/duct.jpg')).readAsBytesSync());

  Future writeOnPdf() async {
    pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,``` the same error

Comment: but if I changed the code to ```class MySecondHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final pdf = pw.Document();
  

  Future writeOnPdf() async {
    final image =
    pw.MemoryImage((File('assets/images/duct.jpg')).readAsBytesSync());
    pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,``` a different error will happen but the screen will be white only

Comment: the new error```E/flutter (18539): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/images/duct.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
E/flutter (18539): #0      _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:635:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I contacted the flutter package maker & he was king enough to guide me to what to do, first he guided me to created the following function out

```
  final data = await rootBundle.load('images/$name');
  return data.buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

Then also he guided me to move the PDF creation method from `statless` to `statfull`
and in the `writePDF()` to add the image as the below code

```
    final image = pw.MemoryImage(await _readImageData('header.png'));
```

now the images are shown in the PDF file with no problems

Answer (score 1):

There is no path to the official file you are trying to add. You can get the file path by right clicking on the picture in the file and clicking copy relative path. then if you are using windows, you can use the file path after converting the '' \ '' s to '/' and putting them under assets in pubseps.yaml.

[image]

Comment: I already added the images folder to ```pubseps.yaml```... but the same result.

Comment: You made the addition wrong. You may have made a mistake on the page. The part where you add pubsepc.yaml must be properly aligned. Please pay attention to her.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMM9ty4Wfq0&ab_channel=Syncfusion%2CInc

Comment: I attached the ```pubspec.yaml```.. all aligned & the routes are done already correctly